# FastLED: "Invalid pin specified" when specifying LED_TYPE from WS2811 to WS2801

Tags: led

I'm trying to run the "DemoReel 100" code from FastLED.

Out of the box, it can be verified.  But when I switch from `#define LED_TYPE    WS2811` to `#define LED_TYPE    WS2801`, I get the error:

> error: static assertion failed: Invalid pin specified
> static_assert(validpin(), "Invalid pin specified");

the line this error originates from is:

```
FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE,DATA_PIN,COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS).setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
```

I can't think of any reason that the LED_TYPE argument should change whether or not a data-pin is valid.  What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  There's two lines for `FastLED.addLeds`, and one needed to be commented out and the other enabled in order have a clock pin work.

```
//  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE,DATA_PIN,COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS).setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE,DATA_PIN,CLK_PIN,COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS).setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip);
```